# Python matplotlib pyplot module always draws on existing figure window when figure title is the same

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am a new python user but an experienced Matlab user. I am recently debugging a python script, and when I manually re-run the script multiple times, I found a somewhat annoying issue of matplotlib: it always draws on existing figure window, overlapping on existing plot, if the figure title is the same.

The script I am debugging looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Some calculations here
plt.figure('Results') # The script will only create one figure
# plot the data
# End of the script
```

A simple search on Google shows that if I don't explicitly specify figure title, or give each figure a different handle, matplotlib can create separate figure windows, and true, it works.

However, is there a way to create multiple figure windows with the same title, without giving them different handles (which in my case, I had to do it manually) in python? In Matlab it will always create separate figure window no matter what figure title you give it.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `figure` is an identifier. If it is left empty anew figure will be created, else the figure with that identifier will be activiated. The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) makes this rather clear:

> `matplotlib.pyplot.figure(num=None, ...)`
>
> `num` : integer or string, optional, default: none
> If not provided, a new figure will be created, and the figure number will be incremented. The figure objects holds this number in a number attribute. If num is provided, and a figure with this id already exists, make it active, and returns a reference to it. If this figure does not exists, create it and returns it. If num is a string, the window title will be set to this figure’s num.

Hence in order to create a new figure, leave this argument out or specify differing ones. In order to set the window's title, use `set_window_title`.

The following will create two figures with the same window title.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.gcf().canvas.set_window_title('Results') 
plt.plot([1,2,3])

plt.figure()
plt.gcf().canvas.set_window_title('Results') 
plt.plot([2,3,1], color="crimson")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the first paragraph of your question, ...

> when I manually re-run the script multiple times, I found a somewhat
>   annoying issue of matplotlib: it always draws on existing figure
>   window

I think that simply clearing the figure (at the start of the script) would make your repeated runs of the script useable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# compute results here - random here as a standin.
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(500)
plt.figure("Results"); plt.clf()
# plot results here...
plt.hist(x, bins=20, histtype='step')
```

Now, each time you run the script, you will draw the results on a blank canvas and not over the top of the old results.

The figures below illustrate the difference, after 3 runs of the script (in ipython): left - without the `plt.clf()`, and right - with `plt.clf()` at the start.

[image: example results]

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest when I wrote the answer yours had not appeared. I removed the part that is more or less the same

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest but feel free to incorporate the other bit into your answer and I'll delete the whole answer

Comment: At the moment I don't even understand this answer. So it might be useful to keep, but you may elaborate a bit on why clearing the figure is an option here. As I see it it would remove the figure's content, such that it will not be plotted?

Comment: ah, ok thanks for the feedback.  The point is to clear the figure at the start of the script (/plotting section), so that you aren't distracted by old results if you run the script >1 time.  But if the 2nd part of the question is what is really desired, i.e., having multiple windows with the same title, then my solution is not relevant and yours is :)

Comment: Now I see why this is working. This is meant to be used in an interactive session, running the same code several times without stopping the interpreter. I'm glad I asked, so now this answer is indeed useful.